# Quick sort, Hoare's partition algorithm. Is there a mistake in CLRS?

Tags: algorithms, sorting, quicksort

The following problem appears in "Introduction to Algorithms" by Thomas Cormen et. al., aka CLRS.

**Problem 7-1.b**

*Hoare's partition algorithm* from the book.

[image]

**Part b:** Assuming the subarray $A[p,\cdots,r]$ contains at least two elements, show that the indices $i$ and $j$ are such that we never access an element of outside the subarray $A[p,\cdots,r]$

---

I think this it is not possible to prove this because this statement is not correct, i.e., during the course of execution we happen to access elements outside the array.
Here I prove the converse of **part b** by using a counter-example.

Consider the array A = [1,2]. Let p = 1 and there r =2.

- Initially, $i = 0$, $j = 3$ and $x = 1$.
- After the loop $5-7$ executes once, $j$ becomes 2 and the condition in line 7 fails resulting the termination of the loop $5-7$.
- Now we reach the loop $8-10$. Now let's look at the state after this loop executes twice. $i = 2$ and the condition in line 10 still holds. Therefore the loop executes a third time and $i$ becomes 3.
- Now to test the condition in line 10 we access $A[3]$ which is outside the subarray $A[1,\cdots, 2]$

---

Is there a mistake in my reasoning or is the problem statement wrong?

Comment: After the loop $5-7$, $j$ becomes $1$ since $A[2] > x$.

Comment: After loop $8−10$, $i$ becomes $1$ since $A[1] = x$.

Comment: Since $i = j = 1$, the algorithm terminates and return $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem statement is correct.

I think you getting confused about: repeat $j \gets j-1$ until $A[j] \leq x$. It means that if $A[j]>x$ then do $j \gets j-1$.

Similarly, loop $8-10$ means that if $A[i]<x$ then do $i \gets i+1$.

Therefore, the algorithm executes in the following way on $A = [1,2]$:

1. After the loop $5-7$, $j$ becomes $1$ since $A[2] > x$.
2. After loop $8−10$, $i$ becomes $1$ since $A[1] = x$.
3. Since $i = j = 1$, the algorithm terminates and returns $1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand now.